# libvirt / kvm guests take very long time to start after host reboot

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu, hangs

Host system is CentOS 6.5 x86_64.  I have setup an Ubuntu guest by following [this wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/KVM).  The guest works, but: if I reboot the host, it takes a very long time (about 30 minutes on the last reboot) before the guests actually start.  If, during this time, I start virsh and do a "list", it just hangs.

Here's a snippet from /var/log/libvirt/libvirt.log:

```
2014-10-14 16:47:11.509+0000: 4668: info : virDomainLoadAllConfigs:14696 : Scanning for configs in /var/run/libvirt/qemu
2014-10-14 16:47:11.527+0000: 4668: info : virDomainLoadAllConfigs:14696 : Scanning for configs in /etc/libvirt/qemu
2014-10-14 16:47:11.527+0000: 4668: info : virDomainLoadAllConfigs:14718 : Loading config file 'mythbuntu.xml'
2014-10-14 16:47:11.529+0000: 4668: info : qemuDomainSnapshotLoad:484 : Scanning for snapshots for domain mythbuntu in /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/snapshot/mythbuntu
2014-10-14 17:14:41.751+0000: 4668: info : virNetDevProbeVnetHdr:94 : Enabling IFF_VNET_HDR
2014-10-14 17:14:41.805+0000: 4668: info : virSecurityDACSetOwnership:296 : Setting DAC user and group on '/home/kvm/mythbuntu.img' to '107:107'
2014-10-14 17:14:41.806+0000: 4668: info : virSecurityDACSetOwnership:296 : Setting DAC user and group on '/mnt/mythtv1/mythbackend_recordings' to '107:107'
2014-10-14 17:14:42.084+0000: 4668: info : lxcSecurityInit:1380 : lxcSecurityInit (null)
```

Notice that huge jump in time, from 16:47:11 to 17:14:41?  The latter time is when the guest actually started, and at this point, "virsh list" was once again usable.

It seems like libvirt/kvm/qemu is getting hung up on something, but eventually is able to proceed.  Anyone have any idea what it might be hung up on?

**Edit:** I am not using snapshots.  And in fact:

```
# ls /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/snapshot/mythbuntu
ls: cannot access /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/snapshot/mythbuntu: No such file or directory
```

The parent looks like this:

```
# ls -R /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/
/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/:
dump  mythbuntu.monitor  save  snapshot

/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/dump:

/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/save:

/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/snapshot:
```

Comment: Are you using snapshots ? The last message before the long time concerning them.

Comment: Looks like it's time to clean up your snapshots.

Comment: Nope, not using snapshots.  I edited the original post to include some more detail on that directory mentioned in the log just before the hang.  It's virtually empty.